# Using SQL REGEXP to find mobile number

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

Our DB can contain the mobile number in different formats, like: '(731) 123-4567' or '731-123 45 67' or '731-12-3-[4567]', etc. 
Also, the input I get in the API for search can be in any of the format.
So, when I need to find a user with mobile in db, I clean up the input number, so it will look like '7311234567' and then wrap/padd it with regexp `'(\\+|\\-|\\(|\\)|\\[|\\]| )*'`, so for example, the SQL looks like this:

```
select * from contact where mobile REGEXP '(\\+|\\-|\\(|\\)|\\[|\\]| )*
             1(\\+|\\-|\\(|\\)|\\[|\\]| )*7(\\+|\\-|\\(|\\)|\\[|\\]| )*
             3(\\+|\\-|\\(|\\)|\\[|\\]| )*1(\\+|\\-|\\(|\\)|\\[|\\]| )*
             2(\\+|\\-|\\(|\\)|\\[|\\]| )*9(\\+|\\-|\\(|\\)|\\[|\\]| )*
             8(\\+|\\-|\\(|\\)|\\[|\\]| )*0(\\+|\\-|\\(|\\)|\\[|\\]| )*
             7(\\+|\\-|\\(|\\)|\\[|\\]| )*4(\\+|\\-|\\(|\\)|\\[|\\]| )*
             0(\\+|\\-|\\(|\\)|\\[|\\]| )*';
```

The problem is when I get input like this '11234567' which is like '7311234567' but without the '73' - when the query executes - it also finds the user with '7311234567'.

Question: How do I wrap my regexp better so it will fit only full number with regexp?

Comment: Did you tried by removing any non numeric character and comparing both ?

Comment: @Alex - I am not in control on saved numbers in DB. The assumption is that they can be in any format, this is why I chosed the regexp solution, but I am not sure how to add to regexp exact match of length. 10x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to install an extra package for this, you just need to add beginning and end anchors to your regex: `^` and `$`.

You can also simplify it to be a bit less verbose:

```
^[^0-9]*7[^0-9]*3[^0-9]*1[^0-9]*1[^0-9]*2[^0-9]*3[^0-9]*4[^0-9]*5[^0-9]*6[^0-9]*7[^0-9]*$
```

Of course the best solution is to normalize your data on input.

Comment: Hi, not sure I uinderstood this. How would you build the query to search for '7311234567'? 10X!

Comment: Same as you were doing: put `[^0-9]*` between each digit, and also add `^` and `$` to the beginning and end.

Comment: Works GREAT :) and the cleanest solution for my needs. Thanks a lot, Uri.

Answer (score 3):

Would something like this work? It uses `REPLACE` as opposed to `REGEX`, but it seems to match your requirements (yes, it is a bit disgusting - see the SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f5e9/8) for a mildly cleaner view). You can add more arguments to further tokenize as necessary:

```
SET @num = '7311234567';

SELECT *
FROM mobile
WHERE 
  REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
      REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
          REPLACE(
            REPLACE(num, ' ', ''), '-', ''), '(', ''), ')', ''), '[', ''), ']', '')

  = 
  REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
      REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
          REPLACE(
            REPLACE(@num, ' ', ''), '-', ''), '(', ''), ')', ''), '[', ''), ']', '')
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work, but how about performance difference between REPLACE (especially the nested REPLACE) vs. REGEXP?

Comment: @urir Definitely something to benchmark - I actually haven't had to use this setup myself. In comparison to the above UDF approach, my solution is likely going to be slower (that seems like a robust package, and I'd put their skills above mine any day :) ).

Answer (score 3):

You could use this [MySQL package](https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp) in order to have `regexp_replace` at your disposal.
Then you can replace all non numeric characters while searching, avoiding the test of different formats.

```
String mobileInput = "(731) 123-4567";
String mobile = mobileInput.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");

String sql = "select * from contact where regexp_replace(mobile, '[^0-9]', '') = ?";
// run your sql query

// or directly on database side without Java
String sql = "select * from contact where regexp_replace(mobile, '[^0-9]', '') = regexp_replace(?, '[^0-9]', '')";
```

By removing non numeric characters, `(731) 123-4567`, `731-123 45 67`, and `731-12-3-[4567]` will give you `7311234567`.

Tested with Oracle because I don't have MySQL installed:

```
select regexp_replace('(731) 123-4567', '[^0-9]', '') as "first",
       regexp_replace('731-123 45 67', '[^0-9]', '') as "second",
       regexp_replace('731-12-3-[4567]', '[^0-9]', '') as "third"
  from dual
```

->

```
     first          second           third
7311234567      7311234567      7311234567
```

Comment: This would be the best solution `String sql = "select * from contact where regexp_replace(mobile, '[^0-9]', '') = ?";` but if I understand correctly - I need to install this package on my DB. Right?

Comment: Yes you will have to install it on your database locally. You can follow this guide that should be somewhat similar: http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_preg/. You will have to compile the C source code into a shared object library `*.so` and then tell mysql where to locate these new functions. See the official page for compiling/installing UDF onto MySQL : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/udf-compiling.html

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure it will get through now... Looks like I will prefer the 'REPLACE' instead.